# Question on scaling object and its impact on rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, transforms

I am modeling a plastic bottle. The plastic bottle is actually 19 mm and 6 mm. However, when I modeled it in that size, I encountered issues with clipping and auto-merging vertices. Instead I worked in centimeters.

My question now is: how does this affect Camera and the rendering, and how does Cycles calculate things? Is it crucial for me to scale everything to the correct size, or can it work since it's relative?

Comment: Hi :). It's generally easier to have the final render in real world size, so that depth of field and light falloff will be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can say, the rendering is affected by the dimensions. If you take a *Point* lamp and set a *Power* of for example 100 W then this might give some realistic light strength if you put it in a room with an area of 4 × 5 m. But due to light falloff, the same lamp will be very dim if you modeled the room in a scale of 100:1 and now it is 400 × 500 m.

Not only renderings are affected, but simulations as well like rigid bodies, soft bodies, cloth, smoke and fluid etc. But sometimes the simulations work better if objects have certain sizes, therefore people sometimes the change speed to make the simulation faster or slower depending on what looks more realistic.

About the *Auto Merge*: first of all you could disable it so that this does not happen even when working on small scales. Although it is sometimes neat if you do not have to merge vertices manually and can help preventing to accidentally have duplicates sometimes, it has the potential danger of messing up objects when vertices are unintentionally merged unnoticed, especially when merge thresholds are too large.

The clipping is only affected by the scale in so far that you can set distances for *Clip Start* and *End*, separate for the *3D Viewport* in the sidepanel under the *View* and also for cameras in their *Camera Properties*. If the model is so small that in order to see it you need to get very close below the clip start distance, it gets clipped. If it's so big that you need to view it from very far away outside the clip end distance, you get the same problem.

So it is not necessary for clipping to model at real world dimensions like for shading or simulations, since you can adjust the clipping as needed - of course you can get away with unreal scales in render or simulation as well if you tweak the settings to a certain degree, it just makes it easier to get something looking realistic if you model it in its correct size.

The most important when changing the clipping is to have a range that is not too wide. For example a start of 0.01 m with an end of 100 or 1000 m is okay, but not 0.001 m and 100000 m. Although 0.01 might already be too large for your small model, so a start of 0.001 m is probably better.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi again! Just a quick question on not setting the clipping range to wide. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: @N03 Sure. It is mostly a matter of floating point precision and hardware limitations. If I have for example values like 0.00001 (10$^{-5}$) and 10,000 (10$^{4}$) this is a factor of 10$^{9}$ from start to end. This will result in artifacts because the calculation of faces and their view distance order gets messed up, like in this example with a 40 m high Suzanne and the above clipping values: [wide clip range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufAy.jpg) It might even look worse when zooming further out: [zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hefc.jpg), sometimes the object might even disappear.

Comment: @N03  Of course these artifacts can be very annoying when trying to model and make it much harder to see what you are doing. But since the object is quite large, there is most likely no need to set the _Clip Start_ so very low because you might not need to get so close, so you could set it higher to 0.1 for example. This already looks much better. And maybe you could set the _End_ value lower as well, if you are not going to zoom very far out. So here is how Suzanne looks with a smaller clipping range: [clip range adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM9Vm.jpg).

Comment: By the way, not only the range from _Start_ to _End_ overall can be problematic, it seems that very low values for the _Start_ are generally producing more artifacts in perspective view, whereas very high _End_ values are producing more artifacts in orthographic view. Read more about the topic in the Blender manual: [_Depth Buffer Glitches_](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#depth-buffer-glitches)

Comment: Thank you Gordon!