# Weird view (fragments) in orthographic view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I use blender 4 and I have set up some very basic geometries.
If in orthographic view I always see some weird rendered faces. When in isometric view it is gone.
I have no idea what change has caused this. It was not there from the beginning. Also restarting did not help.

Any idea why this (bug?) appears?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe check the N panel > View > View > Clip Start and Clip End?

Comment: It is true that this changes things. I have currently set Clip start: 0.001m and Clip End: 1500m.
Because my model is quite big, as it shows a building and I wanted to build it in original sizes (meters). Therefore I had to increase the clip end quite a bit. Changing the value only changes the fragments but it does not resolve the problem...

Any further idea? I think it could be the right direction...

Comment: For more information about the clipping settings read the second half of my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311169/question-on-scaling-object-and-its-impact-on-rendering-in-cycles/311176#311176 Adjusting only the _Clip End_ is not enough.

Comment: maybe share your file? Only keep some objects...

Comment: @moonboots Why? The _Clip Start_ is simply too low. If he increases it to 0.01 or even better to 0.1 the problem will be solved. When the scene is so large I doubt it has to be kept on 0.001 m. More about it in the Blender manual here: [_Depth Buffer Glitches_](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#depth-buffer-glitches)

Comment: I meant if he can fix with the Clip Start and End    ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Thank you very much. This was it!